# Presents (is present)

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, grammaticality-in-context

I came across this usage in a DevExpress support ticket:

- It is automatically checked if the corresponding value presents in the filter.

I think it should be either "is present" or "presents itself", however the latter is unlikely. What do you think about this?

Comment: I would say you are correct in your assessment.

Comment: At first I thought they meant something like "appears", but that can't be it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an intransitive usage for the verb *present*, which is usually seen in medical contexts.

> **present** *v intr*
>    1. To make a presentation.
>   2. *Medicine*
>   - a. To be evident or manifest. Used of a disease or condition: *how Lyme disease presents in its later stages.*
>    - b. To exhibit symptoms or signs during a medical examination: *The patient presented with headache and heel pain.*
>   <sub>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/present)</sub>

It is possible that whoever wrote that was influenced by that usage. I would expect that most readers would not be completely in tune with that expression, however, which is rather a bit strange and highfalutin when found in a support ticket.

Comment: This meaning of *present* does not seem to fit the context. This sense of *present* stresses the visible, or observable quality of the thing that presents. It seems very unlikely that the value in a filter was *made manifest*. The value in the filter is likely not visible at all.

Comment: @Juhasz: You have to view this as a figurative usage, not a literal one. Think: "In my view, this is a disturbing situation." The word *view* there does not mean literally seeing something with the eyes.